# Show alert if the user tries to delete an image which is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm implementing a image delete feature. If the user tries to delete an image which is checked he shoul get an alert that he can't delete the image

```
<img src='" . $dir . $name[$i] . "' width='350' height='200' /> // image1
<input type='radio' name='new_featured_images' id='checked' value='" . $name[$i] . "' checked /> // checked radio button
<a href='' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete' id='featured_image_delete' value='" . $name[$i] . "'></a> //delete link... haven't given the href yet

<img src='" . $dir . $name[$i] . "' width='350' height='200' /> // image2
<input type='radio' name='new_featured_images' id='checked' value='" . $name[$i] . "'/> // unchecked radio button
<a href='' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete' id='featured_image_delete' value='" . $name[$i] . "'></a> //delete link... haven't given the href yet
```

I'm using below shown jquery. I want to show the alert only if the user tries to delete the checked image

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".glyphicon-trash", function() {

    if($('#checked').is(':checked')) { 
        alert("can not delete");
        return false;
    } else{
        var x=confirm("Do you want to delete this image?")
        if (x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;            
    }


});
```

Comment: +1 for providing all the required information in one go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : use `.prev()` to get input radio button and check if it is checked or not

**NOTE** - Please use unique `id` through out the html code as this may fall you into mess and you could not figure out the problem. In your case, radio button and delete button has same `id`, please change it to some unique values.

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".glyphicon-trash", function() {

    if($(this).prev('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) { 
        alert("can not delete");
        return false;
    } else{
        var x=confirm("Do you want to delete this image?")
        if (x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;            
    }

});
```

Comment: @AminJafari, yeah you are correct ... let me mention it